# Angular 4 can't run WaveSurfer in my component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript1.8, wavesurfer.js

I want to run WaveSurfer.js on my Angular project and it does not work like I want to.
WaveSurfer works perfectly in the Index. However, I want the WaveSurfer in my component and it doesn't work.

**Index(Work):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="assets/js/wavesurfer.min.js"></script><
<script src="wavesurfer.microphone.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WaveAngular</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<div id="waveform"></div>
<script src="assets/js/wavesurfer.js">
</script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Component(Doesn't work):**

```
<div class="dashboard-voice-parent">
<div class="dashboard-voice-Visualication">
<div id="waveform"></div>
<script src="assets/js/wavesurfer.js"></script>

 </div>
 <div class="dashboard-voice-buttoncontainer">
  <div class="dashboard-voice-buttonborder ">
 <button type="button" class="dashboard-voice-animated" 
  onclick="microphone.pause()" >
      <img src="/assets/svg/PauseBTN.png" >
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="dashboard-voice-VoiceBTN" 
    onclick="microphone.start()" >
      <img src="/asset`enter code here`s/svg/VoiceBTN.png">
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="dashboard-voice-animated" 
    onclick="microphone.stopDevice()" >
      <img src="/assets/svg/StopBTN.png" >
    </button>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: microphone is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):17)
```

This is my JavaScript code which is in wavesurfer.js

```
  var 
  wavesurfer=WaveSurfer.create({container:'#waveform',waveColor:'grey'});
  var microphone = Object.create(WaveSurfer.Microphone);

  microphone.init({
  wavesurfer: wavesurfer
  });

  microphone.on('deviceReady', function(stream) {
  console.log('Device ready!', stream);
  });
  microphone.on('deviceError', function(code) {
  console.warn('Device error: ' + code);
  });
  microphone.pause();
  microphone.play();  
  microphone.stopDevice();
```

Here is the WaveSurfer I am using: [WaveSurfer.Microphone Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJeGWd)

I hope you guys can help me on this problem!

Comment: Please don't add images but add code in your question, [you can format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thank you for response, I replaced the Images with the actual code. If there are any other shortcomings please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wavesurfer.js Overview](https://wavesurfer-js.org/), you can try installing wavesurfer from npm.

`npm install --save wavesurfer.js@2.0.0-beta01`

According to this [issue on the wavesurfer github page](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/1077), there may be some problems getting the ES6 imports to work correctly with webpack (which Angular 4 uses under the hood). The issue has some details on how  you would go about importing wavesurfer and its plugins into your component.

The `import` statements in your component could then look like this:

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
import Microphone from 'wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.microphone.min.js';
```

I would recommend trying this approach, and get rid of any `<script>` tag references to wavesurfer in your HTML. It's quite a bit cleaner.

Comment: Found this not working if you don't set up 'microphone' option: 

`WaveSurfer.microphone = Microphone;`

Comment: Note that there are no curly braces `{}` on the import statement (signifying the default import). `import { WaveSurfer } from 'wavesurfer.js';` does not work.